# Why was my question closed as "off-topic"?

Tags: support, closed-questions

I have a question about my Server Fault post: ["Welcome to Intellek" when trying to install Windows LTSC 2021 in Qemu](https://serverfault.com/questions/1119771/welcome-to-intellek-when-trying-to-install-windows-ltsc-2021-in-qemu)

Why was my question closed? The close message does not provide enough details, what practices? What is it talking about?

I assume the commented closed this message, he has a high reputation that I assume is enough to close questions, and was talking about how I downloaded a tampered ISO. Problem is, I verified the checksum and they match. Furthermore the problem discussed is displayed by the OFFICIAL ISO as well as the "tampered one (according to the commenter)". I clarified this with him in the comments, so why was it closed? Could it be because he was offended (if so I apologize) or may have not read my reply comment? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I didnt voted to close, but it's a bad practice to download an ISO from an un-official's source.

The close reason reflect that point of view.

I know that seem harsh but the fact it contain another business information inside it seem to indicate that the iso got a problem or was slipstreamed maybe at some point. I cant explain the file hash match, but you can't tell it's not the ISO problem as it's not an official's one either. It's a deadlock at that point.

The actual problem seem to be a Windows Autopilot issue, but is it an issue on Microsoft side or just the ISO in error ? as you are not alone.  (https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10LTSC/comments/1075anp/welcome_to_intellek/)

To be valid to re-open your question try to get the ISO on Microsoft site and retry. After that if the problem go away you will know the ISO was impacted, and if not please edit, and you will be valid to have your question re-openned.

Comment: Yeah, that is literally me. I got not help from there. After getting the error from the official ISO, I downloaded one that was recommended by the LTSC community with the same error. It is most likely a problem with qemu having some hwid associated with Intellek company. Ill edit out the second ISO site to avoid mis-interpretation